# Generic CSS selector for GTM trigger

Tags: css, triggers, css-selectors, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to create a CSS selector to be able to match the following entries (The page-top-menu):

```
Header menu - Menu 1
DE
#page-top-menu > div > div.menu-wrapper > ul > li.i39.dropdown.layer.item-type-1.catid-0eca5a6c6e53f281b9e0469ca3d744fd > a
EN
#page-top-menu > div > div.menu-wrapper > ul > li.i40.dropdown.layer.item-type-1.catid-0eca5a6c6e53f281b9e0469ca3d744fd > a
FR
#page-top-menu > div > div.menu-wrapper > ul > li.i28.dropdown.layer.item-type-1.catid-0eca5a6c6e53f281b9e0469ca3d744fd > a


Header menu - Menu 2

DE 
#page-top-menu > div > div.menu-wrapper > ul > li.i43.dropdown.layer.item-type-2.catid-9268a9eaa067019916390b7d08113781 > a
EN
#page-top-menu > div > div.menu-wrapper > ul > li.i43.dropdown.layer.item-type-2.catid-9268a9eaa067019916390b7d08113781 > a
FR
#page-top-menu > div > div.menu-wrapper > ul > li.i40.dropdown.layer.item-type-2.catid-9268a9eaa067019916390b7d08113781 > a
```

As you can see, they all have this in common:

```
#page-top-menu > div > div.menu-wrapper > ul > li
```

however when I try to create the tigger based on the following selectors, nothing happens:

```
#page-top-menu > div > div.menu-wrapper > ul
#page-top-menu > div > div.menu-wrapper > ul > li
#page-top-menu > div > div.menu-wrapper > ul > li > *
```

If I use the full CSS selectors, the triggers work.

EDIT:

here is an example of one of the html elements (The highlighted part is the one the selector refers to):

[image]

Here is a snapshot of how the Tag and triggers are set up:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a *specificity* issue

Comment: Can you please provide a link to your website or post example of your HTML. Also will be helpful your screenshots from GTM how you configured this triggers and tags

Comment: Added image with html image

Comment: Please add screenshot of your trigger configuration in GTM

Comment: @Paulie_D: Probably not. I'd be surprised if a non-CSS implementation took specificity into account. This looks more like the selector isn't targeting the right elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `a` element has child elements. And when you clicked element inside tag `a` it will fire click event, but click element will point to inner tag. You have two ways how to solve it:

1) Target all children elements in multi levels:

Type: `Click - All Elements`

CSS selector: `#page-top-menu > div > div.menu-wrapper > ul > li *`

2) Target only link:

Type: `Click - Just Links`

CSS selector: `#page-top-menu > div > div.menu-wrapper > ul > li > a`